# Get failed test case count as per parameter

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to run test cases depending on given parameters and, also, get output corresponding to each of the given parameters. I was able to run the Test Cases based on provided parameters by using [JUnit Parameterized Test](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm). My Test class is as follows:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class NumberChecker {

    private final Integer inputNumber;
    private final Boolean isPrime;    
    private final Long sumOfDigits;

    public NumberChecker(Integer inputNumber, Boolean expectedResult, Long sumOfDigits) {
        this.inputNumber = inputNumber;
        this.isPrime = expectedResult;
        this.sumOfDigits = sumOfDigits;
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static List primeNumbers() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            {2, true, 2L},
            {6, false, 6L},
            {19, true, 10L},
            {22, false, 4L},
            {23, true, 5L}
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void testPrimeNumberChecker() {
        assertEquals(isPrime, PrimeNumberChecker.validate(inputNumber));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSumOfDigits() {
        assertEquals(sumOfDigits, SumOfDigits.calculate(inputNumber));
    }

    @Test
    public void testFail() {
        fail("This is a failed test case for parameter " + inputNumber);
    }
}
```

But I'm not able to get parameter-wise output. Following is a snippet from my TestRunner class:

```
printDash();
System.out.println("TEST RESULTS");
printDash();
System.out.println("Passed: " + (result.wasSuccessful() ? "YES" : "NO"));
System.out.println("Total Test Cases: " + result.getRunCount());
System.out.print("Successful: " + (result.getRunCount() - result.getFailureCount() - result.getIgnoreCount()));
System.out.print("  Ignored: " + result.getIgnoreCount());
System.out.println("  Failed: " + result.getFailureCount());
System.out.println("Run Time: " + ((double) result.getRunTime() / 1000) + " seconds");
printDash();
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEST RESULTS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Passed: NO
Total Test Cases: 15
Successful: 10  Ignored: 0  Failed: 5
Run Time: 0.078 seconds
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The output that I want is:

```
Parameter: 2
    Passed: NO
    Test Cases: 3
    Successful: 2  Ignored: 0  Failed: 1

Parameter: 6
    Passed: NO
    Test Cases: 3
    Successful: 2  Ignored: 0  Failed: 1

Parameter: 19
    Passed: NO
    Test Cases: 3
    Successful: 2  Ignored: 0  Failed: 1
```

And, so on.

Is this feasible? If yes, how can it be achieved?

---

**Update:** I should also be able to print output for not only failed test cases but also passed test cases. Something as follows:

```
Parameter: 22
    Passed: YES
    Test Cases: 3
    Successful: 3  Ignored: 0  Failed: 0
```

---

**Related:** An old [issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/45) raised for adding Before and After Parameterized Run annotations with the [junit-team](https://github.com/junit-team) on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution (although not the most appropriate one) that I came up with, is to maintain a *Collection* of the test results pertaining to each parameter. I made the following class for maintaining these data:

```
public class ParameterResult {        
    private int success = 0;
    private int fail = 0;    

    public int getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }    
    public void addSuccess() {
        this.success += 1;
    }    
    public int getFail() {
        return fail;
    }    
    public void addFail() {
        this.fail  += 1;
    }        
}
```

Above is just a basic example I came up with; you could add more info like a list of failed test cases, number of ignored test cases, etc.

Now, in the test class, add a static collection to maintain parameter-wise test results like the following:

```
private static final Map<Integer, ParameterResult> parameterResults = new HashMap<>();
```

I used a `HashMap`.

Add an object of ParameterResult to the collection whenever the constructor of the test class is being called.

```
if (!parameterResults.containsKey(inputNumber)) {
    ParameterResult curParameterResult = new ParameterResult();
    parameterResults.put(inputNumber, curParameterResult);
}
```

Here, `inputNumber` is the parameter against which the checking is being done.

Populate the test results as follows:

```
@Test
public void testPrimeNumberChecker() {
    try {
        assertEquals(isPrime, PrimeNumberChecker.validate(inputNumber));
        parameterResults.get(inputNumber).addSuccess();
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        parameterResults.get(inputNumber).addFail();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Display the test results after all test cases have been performed.

```
@AfterClass
public static void printResult() {
    if (!parameterResults.isEmpty()) {
        parameterResults.entrySet().stream().forEach(pR -> {
            System.out.println("\nParameter: " + pR.getKey());
            System.out.println("\tPassed: " + (pR.getValue().getFail() > 0 ? "NO" : "YES"));
            System.out.print("\tTest Cases: " + pR.getValue().getSuccess() + pR.getValue().getFail());
            System.out.print("  Successful: " + pR.getValue().getSuccess());
            System.out.println("  Failed: " + pR.getValue().getFail());
    }
}
```

I would love to hear from others. Mainly, what are the disadvantages of doing this? And, can it be improved?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, `Parametrized` runner doesn't provide such output. Instead you can use `Theories`

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class NumberChecker  {

    @DataPoints
    public static Integer[] inputNumber(){
        return new Integer[]{2, 6, 19, 22, 23};
    };
    @DataPoints
    public static Boolean[] isPrime(){
        return new Boolean[]{true, false};
    };
    @DataPoints
    public static Long[] sumOfDigits(){
        return new Long[]{2l, 6l, 10l, 4l, 5l};
    };

    @Theory
    public void testPrimeNumberChecker(int inputNumber, boolean isPrime) {
        assertEquals(isPrime, PrimeNumberChecker.validate(inputNumber));
    }

    @Theory
    public void testSumOfDigits(int inputNumber, long sumOfDigits) {
        assertEquals(sumOfDigits, SumOfDigits.calculate(inputNumber));
    }
}
```

You will get following output for `@Theory` that fails

> Failed tests:   NumberChecker.testPrimeNumberChecker
>   testPrimeNumberChecker("2" , "true" )
>
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

The difference is that test will be running with all possible combinations of parameters, not only the ones that you explicit declare. But you can use `Assumptions` to filter data points.

One more things that you can could be done you can also use parameters in your test name with `Parametrized`.

```
@Parameters(name = "inputNumber: {0}, isPrime: {1}, sumOfDigits: {2}")
```

In this case test name will display your parameters.

Comment: But I need to check them in combination. You talk about *"But you can use Assumptions to filter data points"*; how can I do that in this case. Also, what if the data points are supplied by another class.

Comment: @BileshGanguly just use `assumeThat` at the beginnig of the test, and if data points doesn't pass the assumption it will be ignored. I agree, that for you case `Parametrized` is more suitable. But it will not give needed output. On the other hand, for your case `Theories` requires extra assumptions, but it will give you better output.

Comment: Agreed, but I also need to print *"Passed: YES"* when test cases for a parameter pass.

Comment: @BileshGanguly you can display your parameters in test name using `Paraterized` test. Check my edit to answer.